# BufferedReader waits for line return

Tags: java, telnet, bufferedreader

```
package sample_server;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.security.*;

/**
 * Title:        Sample Server
 * Description:  A simple telnet server
 * @author A. Jones
 * @version 0.01
 */

public class Sample_server {

  private static int port=4444, maxConnections=0;
  // Listen for incoming connections and handle them
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int i=0;

    try{
      ServerSocket listener = new ServerSocket(port);
      Socket server;

      while((i++ < maxConnections) || (maxConnections == 0)){
        doComms connection;
        server = listener.accept();
        doComms conn_c= new doComms(server);
        Thread t = new Thread(conn_c);
        t.start();
      }
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
      System.out.println("IOException on socket listen: " + ioe);
      ioe.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

}

class doComms implements Runnable {
    private Socket server;

    doComms(Socket server) {
      this.server=server;
    }

    public void run () {
      try {
        // Get input from the client
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(server.getInputStream()));
        PrintStream out = new PrintStream(server.getOutputStream());
        System.out.println("A user has connected to the server.");
        out.println("You have connected.");
        MenuSystemClass newMenu = new MenuSystemClass(in, out);
        newMenu.MainMenu(server);
      } catch (IOException ioe) {
        System.out.println("IOException on socket listen: " + ioe);
        ioe.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
}
```

Second File

```
/*
 * Menu System Class
 * Simple to use menu
 */
package sample_server;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 * My Custom Menu Class
 * @author aaron
 */
public class MenuSystemClass {
    private BufferedReader input = null;
    private PrintStream output = null;

    MenuSystemClass(java.io.BufferedReader in, PrintStream out) {
        input  = in;
        output = out;
    }

    public void MainMenu(java.net.Socket server) throws IOException {
        // Set Run Boolean to true
        boolean running = true;
        // We switch the input to lowecase here and compare
        while(running) {
            output.println("A: Stuff ; V: Things ; W: More Stuff; S: Also Stuff ; D: Delete ; Q: Quit");
            // Initialize the scanner
            Scanner user_input = new Scanner(input);
            // Get the user input
            String decision = user_input.next();
            // Conver their decision to lowercase and compare to choices.
            switch (decision.toLowerCase()) {
                case "a":
                    output.println("This is not yet implemented.");
                    break;
                case "s":
                    output.println("This is not yet implemented.");
                    break;
                case "d":
                    output.println("This is not yet implemented.");
                    break;
                case "v":
                    output.println("This is not yet implemented.");
                    break;
                case "w":
                    output.println("This is not yet implemented.");
                    break;
                case "q":
                    server.close();
                    System.out.println("A connection has been terminated by the client.");
                    return;
                default:
                    output.println("You did not select a viable option.");
                    output.println("Try again.");
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am attempting to make a telnet server. You can connect to the server but when you do; it requires you to press the enter key twice before it begins to properly accept input. How do I force BufferedReader to skip the necessity for the new line so that as soon as you load up the server it is ready -

What I want -

Welcome to the server.
Type A Or B Or Whatever.
A <-- User input
YOU TYPED A!

What it is doing -
Welcome to the server.
User must press enter
User must press enter
Type A or B or whatever.
A<-- user input
You typed A!

How can I make BufferedReader prepare to take user input immediately?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to read lines, don't call readLine(), and don't us the Scanner class.

BufferedReader has three other read() methods. Use them.

If you want character input from the console, use the Console class.